# Loading ".npy" files for Ultralytics YOLOv8 model

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pytorch, yolov8

Is there a way to load `.npy` files for training YOLOv8 model? I am trying to use the YOLO model to train on Hyperspectral images which I have preprocessed using the `spectral` library and stored them as an `.npy` files.

I have stored the images according to the dataset format provided in the Ultralytic documentation. I am using the following configuration file for the dataset:

```
path: F:\Sem-VI\Code\dataset # dataset root dir
train: train # train images (relative to 'path') 118287 images
val: val # val images (relative to 'path') 118287 images

# Classes
names:
  0: somethin
```

However, training the model with the above configuration gives the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError:
Dataset 'config.yaml' images not found ⚠️, missing path 'F:\Sem-VI\Code\dataset\val'
Note dataset download directory is 'F:\yolo-ultralytics\datasets'. You can update this in 'C:\Users\Tests\AppData\Roaming\Ultralytics\settings.yaml'
```

I would be happy if anyone could help. Thank you.

I tried using relative as well as absoulte paths, however nothing seems to work. I searched around the net, but couldn't find anything useful that could help me.

Comment: i m afraid u hav to change source code

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar, I also think thats the only option left, but I am a bit confused about the source code, and somehow couldn't figure how the library loads the dataset. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/6183b59d8a1c3fe67ed1a6fab093799a8a85cbe7/ultralytics/data/base.py#L100 @T090 Subhashish Nabajja